# Are nested functions possible in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I want to nest one function inside another in NEO4J like:

```
toFloat(coalesce(row.name, "UNKNOWN"))
```

But if I do so, it seems like coalesce isn't working. The Error message:

> Neo.ClientError.Statement.SemanticError: Cannot merge node using null
>   property value for name

If I get rid of toFloat function, then coalesce works.

What can I do to combine these 2 functions?

Answer (score 0):

You can nest functions within Cypher. The error message you are receiving suggests that some of your row values do not have a property set for name, hence returning a null.